# React Native Bug: selectable doesn't work with justify text-alignment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text-alignment

I'm creating an reading aplication, but when I use at the same time textAlign: justify and selectable={true}, the justify alignment doesnt work. I'm testing on Android, version 10>+. Can someone help me?

```
<Text 
selectable={true}
style={{textAlign: 'justify'}}
> 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
</Text>
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it works, https://snack.expo.dev/@rvx/f6feef.
Can you add more information?

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, but did you try on android and with a big text? I tried on Expo and it didn't work. Try this one: https://snack.expo.dev/@rauleffting/brave-nachos

Comment: What do you mean by big text? Long text? The snack url you gave, I've tried it on the built in Android device and my own Android device. When selectable is true, I can select the text, and when it is false, I am unable to select the text. Do you have more information about what you are doing?